# Private file system for attachments

Tags: uploads, media-library, filesystem

Is there a way to make an attachment private? This also includes moving the files to a separate folder for private attachments, even if it's a sub-folder of **uploads**, to restrict anonymous access fully.

Answer (score 0):

Victor,

Maybe this is helping you.

http://goo.gl/9sahyp

Regards,
Hugo

Comment: The plugins seems quite outdated ... Compatible up to: 2.8.4 so I can't accept your answer, thanks though.

PS. Moreover it seems that it prevents the whole **uploads** directory, since I want to protect only a part of it, leaving the default ones public.